# PHP Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: php, curl

I get this error:

"Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"

When doing:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://example.com' . ($method == 'GET' && $params ? '?' . $params : ''));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
$response = curl_exec($curl);

print curl_error($curl)
```

Works ok on another server.

The SSL is using NSS.
PHP 5.3.6

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099849/amazon-marketplacewebserviceorders-requests-suddenly-failing-php-curl-giving-ss

Comment: I know this is a little bit of an old question but could you pick a "correct answer"?

Comment: already picked what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by renaming the nssdb:

```
mv /etc/pki/nssdb /etc/pki/nssdb.old
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me for some reason. It seems like the problem was caused by upgrade of libcurl. In my case I don't want any validation whatsoever but I can't seem to be able to disable the whole thing. Does anybody have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 27):

Had this happen to two servers which use the PayPal IPN, both at around the same time.

Fix was to restart Apache.

Comment: Had it happen too. An automatic update had happened, which created a new /etc/pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt (and moved the old one to /etc/pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt.rpmnew). File contents were the same. There were no warnings or other information in the logs. 

I have no idea if the automatic update was the culprit though. Anyhow, a restart of php-fpm did solve the issue.

Comment: Worth mentioning for me at least that a simple graceful restart of Apache wasn't enough. I had to restart the service (i.e. `service httpd restart`). Not sure why that made the difference, but it did.

Comment: For those who use nginx + php-fpm on CentOS: `sudo service php-fpm restart` should do the trick

Comment: I can confirm that this helped me as well. After going up and down trying to find why cURL in PHP would work on the CLI but not in Apache, a simple Apache restart fixed the issue. RHEL 6.5.

Comment: Was this successful for anyone running a Jetty server?

Answer (score 13):

If you are getting "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)" it may very well mean that you have either deleted everything from `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` or have set invalid permissions (CHMOD).

If you are using RHEL/CentOS, try `yum reinstall openssl ca-certificates -y`

Comment: This, not restarting/rebooting helped me.

Comment: And probably `apt-transport-https` too

Answer (score 7):

Just upgraded to PHP 5.5.17 and this is when the trouble started. The server runs PayPal transactions and cURL started failing on this error: "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)".

I tried regenerating the certs, modifying the curl options, nothing was getting me anywhere. **The solution was to simply reboot the server** (CentOS 6.5 in my case). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I concur; rebooting the server fixed the problem for me also :)

Answer (score 1):

It happen to me after update of packages.

Once I restarted the apache it got fixed.

Then I installed it at production server and I got it again. 
This time it was mess at the certificates under /etc/pki/tls/certs/

Backup the files and this command will fix it:

`curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, you need to install CA certificates to allow SSL-based applications to check for the authenticity of SSL connections by:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

See: [cURL not working (Error #77) for SSL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55859036/55075)