# WWW::Curl returns error 77 but Curl from command line succeeds

Tags: ssl, curl

I'm trying to use Google's URL shortener service.  The call from the command line succeeds:

> curl -v https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url -H
>   'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"longUrl":
>   "http://www.google.com"}'

However, the equivalent using WWW::Curl::Easy returns an error code of 77.  We've checked that the `ca-bundle.crt` file is world-readable as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064601/curl-not-working-error-77-for-ssl-connections-on-centos-for-non-root-users).  I'm really stumped. Any suggestions of things to try would be appreciated.

The Perl code works on our development server but is failing on the staging server so the code is correct.

Comment: Have you compared versions of curl, Perl, and WWW::Curl::Easy on the dev and production servers?

Comment: Check the path to the cert.  It looks like error 77 is CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE : Problem with reading the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to corrupt or missing SSL chain certificate files in the PKI directory. 
You’ll need to make sure the files ca-bundle, following steps:
In your console/terminal:

```
mkdir /usr/src/ca-certificates && cd /usr/src/ca-certificates
```

Enter this site: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ca-certificates , get your ca-certificate, for SO.
Copy url of download and paste in url:
    wget your_url_donwload_ca-ceritificated.rpm
now, install yout rpm:

```
rpm2cpio your_url_donwload_ca-ceritificated.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

now restart your service:
my example this command:

```
sudo service2 httpd restart
```

very great
good look

Answer (score 0):

In my case "I was trying to use curl in cpp to perform a GET request" I tried solutions from : [Curl in C++ - Can't get data from HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479534/curl-in-c-cant-get-data-from-https)
the only thing that worked for me was to disable SSL verify peer using :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```