# cURL not working for https giving 77 error in php

Tags: php, curl

I updated my curl to work on https. It does work on terminal however when I use cUrl in php it doesn't work for any https based url.

The error code i get is 77. I have looked into other solutions but no solution is working at all.

I have already tried adding verifyHost, SSL v  6, return transfer nothing works

A simple code is

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com");

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $error = curl_error($ch);
        $number = curl_errno($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $response = array(
            'Result' => array(
                'error'=> $error,
                'number' => $number,
                //'message'=>$fields,
                'count'=> $response
            ));
        $this->jsonOutput($response);
```

In terminal `curl https://www.google.com` works fine.

What is going on, the curl in php was working just fine before.

Comment: The question does not look the same, but I think this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064601/curl-not-working-error-77-for-ssl-connections-on-centos-for-non-root-users

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of php running on your server?

Comment: No just one. It was working fine but to install mongodb, I did yum update curl.

Comment: try to run a curl --version, what version did you get?

Comment: version is curl 7.29.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using yum, i assume you are working on a CentOS distro.

I have made a brief research and it seems it could be an issues with the NSS centos package, triggered by your `yum update`. You could try some basic process restart.

Try to restart your httpd service:

```
service httpd restart
```

Or via apache:

```
apachectl stop
apachectl start
```

and your php-fpm

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```