# git fetch error when fetching on jenkins script

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, pipeline

I'm having issue fetching code from **HTTPS** gitlab using jenkins pipeline, it's giving me error timeout as below. I don't have any issue fetching repo from **HTTP** gitlab server.

NOTE:

1. My jenkins server and **HTTPS** gitlab server are in the internal network, and I have cleared the network firewall.
2. No issue accessing the **HTTPS** gitlab webpage via browser.
3. No issue when fetching repo from my **HTTP** gitlab server.
4. My **HTTPS** gitlab server is using self signed cert.

Below are the error messages in jenkins console output, I have masked the git repo URL for confidential purpose.

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git/': Operation timed out after 300042 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:618)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:847)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1224)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage "Build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I would appreciate the help if anyone encountered the same and how you guys resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Appears to be a network issue? Does your GitLab server use standard ports (80 for http 443 for https)? Locally, do you use http, https, or ssh to fetch the repos?

Comment: @sytech I use https to fetch the repos. my https is tcp port 443

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you don't have open ports between Jenkins and GitLab. Maybe Jenkins has a different route to the GitLab server that's not open? Can you login to the Jenkins server and try to `curl` or `ping` the GitLab server? It might also help if you can describe the network setup. Where are you hosting GitLab and Jenkins? Are you using AWS? Kubernetes? Etc.

Comment: my jenkins and gitlab are on-premise, gitlab doesn't accept ping hence it's not pingable. Im able to telnet 443. Is ping needed and will it affect fetching?

Comment: No, `ping` doesn't necessarily need to work, but it normally _should_ work if you ping your host and the ICMP port is open. Can you use `curl` to contact gitlab using **https** from Jenkins?

Comment: I tried curl my gitlab using https and it just stuck as shown below until I CTRL + C to exit




[xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx ~]$ curl -v https://xxxxx.xxxxxxx
* About to connect() to xxxxx.xxxxxxx port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xxxxx.xxxxxxx...
* Connected to xxxxx.xxxxxxx (xxxxx.xxxxxxx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Comment: Hmmmm. It should eventually timeout and give you a descriptive error. Maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064601/curl-not-working-error-77-for-ssl-connections-on-centos-for-non-root-users)?

Comment: After firewall open for ICMP port between my jenkins and gitlab server, I managed to curl  from jenkin and also managed to git checkout via jenkins pipeline.

we can conclude that ICMP port is required other than https/http