# Paypal sandbox not responding to cUrl call

Tags: php, curl, paypal-sandbox

I try to set up a **Paypal** payment method on a website I'm working on.

However when I send a **cUrl** request in **PHP** to the sandbox I get this cUrl error :

> Error 77 : Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Here is my code :

```
$request = "&USER=myUser".
            "&PWD=myPwd".
            "&SIGNATURE=mySignature".
            "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout".
            "&CANCELURL=myCancelUrl".
            "&RETURNURL=myReturnUrl".
            "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=myPaymentAmount".
            "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR".
            "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE".
            "&LOCALECODE=countryCode".
            "&VERSION=122";

$ch = curl_init("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

    $result_paypal = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$result_paypal)
        echo 'Error '.curl_errno($ch).' : '.curl_error($ch);
```

Paypal sandbox url, credentials, url parameters are fine as when I click my express checkout button I get the token in the opened page :

> TOKEN=EC%2d7NT30345MB*******&TIMESTAMP=2015%2d05%2d28T11%3a36%3a57Z&CORRELATIONID=b539dd0******&ACK=Success&VERSION=122&BUILD=16837281

Facts :

- request is fine, obviously (I get back the token),
- As I use a `signature` in the call I shouldn't need a certificate,
- Tried with and without the `?` at the end of the URL (and did modify accordingly my call)
- Changed `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to 1 and 0, didn't change anything
- Tried http_build_query() with an array of parameters, same result

I don't know what I could have missed.

Did anyone encounter this ?

Comment: What happens if you change `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`?

Comment: Also, you could create your POST variable list as an array and curl will automatically change it to the query string format for you.

Comment: Edited my post with your feedbacks, sadly I already had tried those options

Comment: I'm going to update your code to make it clear what I meant.

Comment: Testing the code as I edited it, there is no curl error response, just the returned query string.

Comment: @Anthony Please do not edit the question, this makes it hard to see the source problem without looking at the history. Provide an answer instead.

Comment: I warned him I would. They can revert if needed. @user3241019 - Try installing a local cert for curl, as found at: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html  I did that awhile back and maybe that's why I'm not seeing the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179216/php-problem-with-the-ssl-ca-cert-path-access-rights)