# Authorize.net CIM returning blank response

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am using PHP SDK for Authorize.net CIM, and all of sudden it stops working.
It is returning the blank response while creating the customer profile. I tried updating the cert file as well but nothing worked.

This is the code:

```
    $authorizeNetCim = new AuthorizeNetCIM($clientRow->authorizenet_login_id,     $clientRow->authorizenet_transaction_key);
    $customerProfile = new AuthorizeNetCustomer;
    $customerAddress = new AuthorizeNetAddress;
    if (!$personRow->hasAuthorizenetProfileId()) {
        $customerProfile->merchantCustomerId = $personRow->id;
        $customerProfile->description        = $personRow->getName();

        $response = $authorizeNetCim->createCustomerProfile($customerProfile);
```

And here is the response:

```
AuthorizeNetCIM_Response Object
(
    [xml] => 
    [response] => 
)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is very urgent, I am looking for possible cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway I have figured out the issue. Have to reboot the apache to make it working. Thanks for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081579/6648864